# How can I make a Python script parse command line arguments like a Unix command?

Tags: python, subprocess, sys, os.walk

I have a Python utility script that accepts arguments in the commandline and executes tasks against an open source search tool called [Elasticsearch](http://www.elasticsearch.org/).

But simply put, here is how it's currently being used:

```
Myscript.py create indexname http://localhost:9260
Myscript.py create indexname http://localhost:9260 IndexMap.json
```

I would like to make it so that the user of the script doesn't have to remember the order of the arguments to the script. How can I enable this in my script? I was thinking along the lines of a Unix-like argument passing. For example:

```
import os
import sys
import glob
import subprocess 

# collect command line arguments
commandline_args = sys.argv

# How to use this simple API:
#   create indexname http://localhost:9260 IndexMap.json

command_type = commandline_args[1]
index_name = commandline_args[2]
base_elasticsearch_url = commandline_args[3]
file_to_index = sys.argv[4] if len(sys.argv) > 4 else None


def run_curl(command, url):
    cmd = ['curl', command]
    url = url.split(' ')
    print 'sending command: '
    print cmd+url    
    return subprocess.check_output(cmd+url)

if (command_type == 'delete'):
    print 'About to run '+ command_type + ' on Index: ' + index_name
    command = '-XDELETE'
    composed_url = base_elasticsearch_url + '/' + index_name + '/'
    output = run_curl(command, composed_url)
    print 'output:'
    print output

# create Index # works!
# curl -XPOST 'localhost:9260/icrd_client_1 -d @clientmappings.json
if (command_type == 'create'):
    print 'About to run '+command_type+' for Index: '+index_name+' from filename: '+file_to_index
    command = '-XPOST'
    composed_url = base_elasticsearch_url + '/' + index_name +' -d ' + '@'+file_to_index
    output = run_curl(command, composed_url)
    print 'output:'
    print output
```

Comment: `import argparse` would be a good place to start.

Comment: @sweeneyrod `argparse` requires version 2.7 or newer.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Python 2.7 or newer, try [`argparse`](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/argparse.html). For older versions, try [`optparse`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/optparse.html)

Comment: I have python: 2.7.5. The argparse looks like a very clunky mammoth. would you provide an example for how i can use it in my code? Do I need the sys.argv anymore?

Comment: I don't understand the comment "The argparse looks like a very clunky mammoth." Can you be more specific?

Comment: Well my real question is if there is a better tutorial I can use for argparse.. The one on the python site is a reference and I'm no expert at python. Any quick simple tutorials on this subject?

Comment: Is [this tutorial](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/argparse.html) more helpful?

Comment: `args = parser.parse_args()` << what does this do exactly? In my example, I can access the commandline entries like this: `command_type = commandline_args[1]`.. I don't understand the deal with parser.parse_args()..

Comment: Open a Python interpreter and try it. It's not difficult to figure out. Make a simple program like the one from the tutorial, and then just start passing command line args and printing stuff.

Comment: I don't understand how this will allow order independence?

Answer (score 1):

I'll suggest a simple elegant solution using python Dictionary, you can use the dictionary `key` instead using `if` statement, it's not the best option i'm sure it's just a bit more elegant.

```
import sys

def func1():
    print "I'm func1"

def func2():
    print "I'm func2"

def func3():
    print "I'm func3"

def func4():
    print "I'm default!"

def main():

    myCommandDict = {"arg1": func1(), "arg2": func2(), "arg3": func3(), "default": func4()}

    commandline_args = sys.argv

    for argument in commandline_args[1]:
        if argument in myCommandDict:
            myCommandDict[argument]
        else:
            myCommandDict["default"]

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Edit main can be replaced with this option:

```
myCommandDict = {"arg1": func1, "arg2": func2, "arg3": func3, "default": func4}

commandline_args = sys.argv[1:]

for argument in commandline_args:
    if argument in myCommandDict:
        myCommandDict[argument]()
    else:
        myCommandDict["default"]()
```

Comment: This doesn't make sense to me. You have function calls as the values in the dictionary, so what you have is `{"arg1": None, "arg2": None, "arg3": None, "default": None}`. I think you want `"arg1: func1` and `myCommandDict[argument]()` instead. Also, you could replace the `"default"` key by using `myCommandDict.get(argument, func4)()` instead of the `if` `else` statements.

Comment: @sweeneyrod It can work both ways (tested), but i made an edit for the other option as you suggested with i have to say is a better approach.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [Getopt](http://docs.python.org/2/library/getopt.html)(it works in a similar way to GNU Getopt)